# Where to find research of React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

Anyone have any good documentary or research for how much in reality React Native application code base is shared and how much of the code is platform specific?

Also same thing with moving from React to React Native, how much you can reuse the code. I know you have to do the UI again, but how about the other code?

I tried to Google both a lot, but could not find any serious case.

Comment: I think that this is a good one -> https://hackernoon.com/transitioning-from-react-web-to-react-native-development-c8e6df57a92e

Comment: Thank you for you help, but actually I have checked that one already. More specific, what I was looking for is more statistics, more specific info than general ideas.

Comment: maybe solve your problem -->>   
 https://github.com/Awadhesh786/ReactNativeExample